# Hall effect sensor model in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, hall-effect

[image]I am working on hall effect based current meter and I run into some troubles running my simulation in LTspice. To be precise I am no sure how to accurately model hall effect sensor. In less accurate models I treated hall effect sensor as voltage source proportional to flux. Now I modelled Hall effect sensor as Wheatstone bridge in order to reflect internal resistance. However not to sure how to relate magnetic flux and change in resistance. I am assuming there is relation between change in resistance and flux as there is definitely relation between change in flux and change in hall voltage. Should I simply apply Ohm’s law?

Comment: Why not add a series resistance and treat it as a  Thevenin source? The output resistance of an unamplified Hall sensor is fairly high, and you don't want to load it significantly, most sensors have an ampliier built in to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try Thevenin equivalent. Sadly, this sensor is very basic. I believe it is simply Hall plate. It requires constant current or voltage and instrumentational amplifier on the output. I tried following model. Voltage across bridge represents hall voltage in presence of magnetic flux (I hope).